# IP Route resets after restart

Tags: networking, network-manager, docker, routing

I have an IP Route that's been created by `docker-compose`, here is the relevant line from `ip route show`:

```
172.17.0.0/16 dev br-a5625859b0ca proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

This clashes with resources on the network that use this range so I use `nm-connection-editor` and move it. Afterwards it looks like this:

```
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-a5625859b0ca proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 metric 425 linkdown
```

and everything works as it should.

My problem is that I am unable to "pin" that and each time I restart my Ubuntu 20.04 machine it resets to the 172.17.0.0/16 range and I have to go through that dance again. How do I save/pin that setting to make it permanent?

Comment: This should help: [serverfault - configuring docker not to use the 172...](https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range).

I used https://serverfault.com/a/942176/391629 and worked for me.

Comment: If you create a static route to the range that is in use I wonder will docker still create the conflicting network.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @jtessier72 - unfortunately those didn't work. I'll continue hacking at this.

Comment: What is in your docker-compose?

Comment: There are a few docker-compose files. I work in a large Enterprise and on several projects and there are multiple projects that have multiple compose files and each are different.